# Binding won't update TabLayout custom title view

Tags: android, data-binding, mvvmcross

In MvvmCross 4.x I created a Android `TabLayout` with custom `Views` as title/header.
The custom `Views` are bound to some text and a number (displayed as badge).

It all works fine. However, when updating (increasing) the number for the badge the tab header view won't follow. 
I needed to create a custom binding for the headers, but I think I did something wrong here.

I use the following code after the tab `Fragment` and `ViewModel`s are created:

```
var bindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(Context, (IMvxLayoutInflaterHolder)Context,
    FragmentStatePagerAdapter.TryGetTabViewModel(tabIndex));
var view =  bindingContext.BindingInflate(tabTitleResourceId, null);

var tab = TabLayout.GetTabAt(tabIndex);
tab.SetCustomView(view);
```

Then the View (tab headers) get refreshed once, but then no more.

Any ideas why the Views are not updated?

I use `MvxFragment` (from Support library) combined with a `MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter`, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solution was keeping the MvxAndroidBindingContext alive somewhere.

So, the following not great code should work.

```
var bindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(Context(IMvxLayoutInflaterHolder)Context,
FragmentStatePagerAdapter.TryGetTabViewModel(tabIndex));
tabCachedBindingsList.Add(bindingContext);
var view =  bindingContext.BindingInflate(tabTitleResourceId, null);

var tab = TabLayout.GetTabAt(tabIndex);
tab.SetCustomView(view);
```